# (pycharm) Differences between importing in interactive console and command line

Tags: python, pycharm

I am currently using pycharm to write python but am hitting an annoying road block in terms of importing local code. I am sure its due to the way I've configured pycharm but I can't figure it out.

My project looks like this

```
project_folder
     |
     |___code
     |     |__ __init__.py
     |     |__ funs.py
     |     |__ prog.py
     |    
     |___Other folders
```

So within prog.py  I have `import funs`  which works fine when I run `python ./code/prog.py` from the `project_folder` level.  However when I'm in interactive console in pycharm this errors. The only way I can get it to work in the interactive console is to run `import code.funs`.

Running

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

in both the interactive console and from the command line returns `D:\\project_folder` so I'm at a bit of a loss for why this is behaving so differently.

Comment: The interactive console doesn't share a namespace with the code in the editor. If your code does an import and you need that import to test something in the console, you need to import it into the console session too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `python ./code/prog.py` Python adds `code` to `PYTHONPATH` so `import funs` resolves. When running in PyCharm by default only the project root is added to `PYTHONPATH` so `funs` can't be found.

A simple workaround is to mark `code` directory as source root with **right-click | Mark Directory as ... | Source Root**. PyCharm will add all source roots to `PYTHONPATH`.

`sys.path.append('./code/')` works the same, but it's a little bit ugly I believe.

Answer (score 0):

For reference I managed to fix the problem by including

```
import sys
sys.path.append('./code/')
```

at the top of my program